# How can I express multiple property in one line of transform, transition?

Tags: css, transform, transition

```
  transform: translateX(25px) ;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
```

Can I compress above sentence into one sentence?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No. the `transform` and `transition-*` properties are unrelated to each other.

It may be possible to combine the two `transition-*` properties using the [`transition` shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition), but that may reset other `transition-*` properties that you didn't show. Also keeping the properties separate makes the CSS better readable (which should be a priority over creating shorter source code).

```
transition: 0.25s 0.05s;
```